# Retry start of a custom Camel endpoint/consumer until server resource becomes available

Tags: apache-camel

I have a custom endpoint and consumer that subscribe to changes in an LDAP server by placing a persistent query.

When the route using the endpoint starts the LDAP server might not be reachable and creating the connection in the consumer fails. So far I am throwing an exception and Camel marks the consumer as stopped. And that is that. (Plus some errors I do not quite understand from "direct" routes that the LDAP route calls. But that is a different matter.) What I would like to happen is to fail the start gracefully and retry. Either

- fail the start of the route, retry until the connection can be established, or
- fail the start of the consumer, retry until connection can be established

Is either of the two "proper" Camel component behavior? If yes, how can I achieve it? If not, how should I go about this?

Another way I probably could get it to work is to report success when creating the consumer even though the LDAP connection cannot be established. Then spin off a thread that tries to create the connection and place the persistent query at certain intervals. But this feels wrong to me because the route/endpoint/consumer will be in status "started" but really are dysfunctional until the connection to the directory server can be established.

I looked at the camel-jms component how it goes about the `testConnectionOnStartup` setting, that is when it is set to `false`. To me it looks like everything will be in state "started" even though the connections are not valid.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you could make use of Camel's redelivery policy.

http://camel.apache.org/redeliverypolicy.html

You can find some examples of it here too:

http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-retry-processing-a-message-from-a-certain-point-back-or-an-entire-route.html

This way each time you catch the exception you're throwing and redeliver the message X number of times. If the message still fails then, drop it into a dead letter queue.

Comment: As you say, the redelivery policy only works for messages. At least that is my understanding. In my case I cannot establish the connection to the server that should send the message when my custom endpoint is started. So there will never be a message. I was wondering whether there is something like a retry policy for route start/stop.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly you're starting a route where part of the start criteria is to connect to a LDAP server which might be down. Camel automatically starts all routes defined in the camel context at launch. I haven't heard of any retry policy for starting and stopping routes though. I know you can start and stop routes [from other routes](http://camel.apache.org/how-can-i-stop-a-route-from-a-route.html) but that's probably not what you're looking for.